# d3.js - How to group/stack data by the value of a field

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Stacked and grouped visualisations in d3 seem to often be created from data in the below format. I'll use the example of a work log, containing hours worked on a topic for an indexed day:

```
Day - Java - Web
 1    4.0    3.5
 2    3.0    1.0
 3    2.0    3.5
```

Such that the first object in the data array might be represented:

```
{day: 1, Java: 4.0, Web: 3.5}
```

Instead, is there a a way to create stacked/grouped charts from data formatted like this:

```
Day - Topic - Hours
 1    Java    4.0
 1    Web     3.5
 2    Java    3.0
 2    Web     1.0
 3    Java    2.0
 3    Web     3.5
```

That is to say - can the groupings of data be determined by the value of a property (in this case Topic), instead of by harcoding the two topics as their own properties. It seems much more flexible - but I have been struggling to find an example of this implementation. Does the data join dictate that you cannot do the above?

Comment: You certainly can. Depending on the particular example you have in mind and the data format it uses, you may have to do some reformatting.

Comment: It looks like you'd use something like `d.nest`. See [these helpful examples of how to use it](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/).